# How to keep track of one php variable in another php file in command line without any session concept?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to give user an option to register into the system and want to link the page to another php file say detail.php page with all the database variable remain active in that file. Please anyone can help me out..??

Answer (score 1):

Other alternatives are cookies, (encrypted) POST parameters sent to that page or if you are using `include` statement to include the contents of that file in the current page, you may as well define your variables just before `include` and those can be used in the included file.

P.S.: Use of sessions is recommended; though its not clear from your question, why you dont intend to use sessions.

Comment: If I have one database file to insert the user details while registering it and in another file say detail.php I want to use that user name and password to continue with the same user...but include() statement is including the whole file...I need just the database variables...

Comment: then why not POST the details entered by the user to your detail.php page?

Comment: But bro I am not using form elements.. I am executing it in a terminal..Its fully php..

Comment: That you should have mentioned in the question. Anyways you can always use `$_GET` and send details like `detail.php?user=user&pwd=pwd`

Answer (score 0):

Any options you may have rely on the client sending some form of way of identifying the initial user.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Keep resending all of the data you need to complete the registration to every page via a form (i.e. as either GET or POST data).
2. Storing the data in a COOKIE and sending that with each request.
3. Storing the data serverside and using the session (and PHP session COOKIE)

Personally, I'd recommend sticking with using the session as it limits the amount of data being sent between requests. The only reason I can think of not to do this is if you multiple application servers and no shared storage for your sessions (i.e. memcache or database)

If you want to elaborate on your OP and explain why you don't want to use sessions, I'd be happy to give you a more indepth answer.

Comment: Thanks hafichuk..Let me explain what exactly I want is I have one file called registration.php. Now I am allowing user to enter the registration details in that file and I am storing their response. Now I want to move to the next file called detail.php to show user more details about the system.. So how can I restore my database variable in this file to fetch the same user detail whenever I want...But I have written this program in command line and I am executing it in a command line..So I just want to know whether it is possible or not..?? Please help me..

Comment: If they are two separate requests from a browser, then you need to do one of the 3 things I listed. PHP doesn't have application scope for variables so you need some other mechanism to share data between requests.

Comment: Thank you so much..I will try some other alternative then if possible...Happy new year anyways..